# How a Method Reference to an instance method is working without new() in this example?

Tags: java, method-reference

In Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getGrade,....); getGrade() method is used without new keyword. Method getGrade is not a static method. How it is working without new

```
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        var ls = Arrays.asList(new Student("S1", Student.Grade.A),
                new Student("S2", Student.Grade.A),
                new Student("S3", Student.Grade.B),
                new Student("S4", Student.Grade.C),
                new Student("S5", Student.Grade.F));

        var group = ls.stream().filter(student -> student.getGrade() != Student.Grade.F).collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getGrade, Collectors.mapping(Student::getName, Collectors.toList())));
        System.out.println(group);
         
    }
}
```

**Lamda format**

```
    var group1 = ls.stream().filter(student -> student.getGrade() != Student.Grade.F).collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(student -> student.getGrade(), Collectors.mapping(student -> student.getName(), Collectors.toList())));
```

In Student class getGrade method is not a static method.

```
class Student {
    public static enum Grade {
        A, B, C, D, F
    }

    private String name;
    private Grade grade;

    public Student(String name, Grade grade) {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + ":" + grade;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Grade getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(Grade grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method reference matches `Function<Student, Grade>`. When the compiler looks at the method `Student::getGrade`, it sees that that method takes *zero* parameters, so it uses the `Student` object passed to `apply` as the implicit first parameter. (This will work for any functional interface where the abstract method exactly matches the referenced method except that it takes an additional first parameter of the target type.) In lambda form, it would look like this:

```
(element) -> element.getGrade()
```